# escaping jquery .html expression

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to use the following jquery expression tonight. It looks as if this expression does not work.

```
$("#mt-message").html('<li class="' + messageLevel.toLowerCase() + '"><a href="#" target="_self">' + message + '</a></li>');
```

Instead I had to use something else which did work but which I would rather not use.

```
$('#mt-news')
    .append(
    $('<li>').append( 
            $('<a>').attr('class', messageLevel.toLowerCase())
                    .attr('href','#')
                    .attr('target','_self')
                    .append(message)
    )                           
);
```

Can someone please help me with the first expression and why it does not work? If the first expression is not possible with the second expression if I use it multiple times do I have to first remove the #mt-news content before appending?

thanks

Comment: Your second option is much clearer

Comment: What does your error log say? The first one looks fine, and it should work..

Comment: Someone edited the question to close the toLowerCase() call with a closing parentheses. Is that what you have in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#mt-message").html('<li class="' + messageLevel.toLowerCase() + '"><a href="#" target="_self">' + message + '</a></li>');
```

toLowerCase() method call was not closed in the original question you posted. The current version (that was edited by someone else) shows the correct call to `toLowerCase()` though.

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is fine, so one of two things could be happening:

1). The element with that ID does not exist on that page (Perhaps could be the case, since the ID's in the two examples are different --)

2). One of those variables is not defined..

Check your error log / console , and see what it says -